Laravel / Filament - Log in via iFrame not working (SameSite)
I have a Laravel application with Filament v3. When I try to log in to the application via the domain name directly, everything works fine. However, when I try to log in via an iFrame, it just reloads the login page and nothing further happens.
I have set the following in my ENV:
SESSION_SAME_SITE=none

Further, when I check the network tab, it shows that it is only the XSRF-TOKEN that applies the "SameSite = None":


I was able to solve this by specifying the SameSite value directly in the .env file as below:
SESSION_PATH="/;SameSite=None; secure"


Try to set no value to it like:
SESSION_SAME_SITE=

Or you can remove this line if no value.
Thanks.
